I want a php file to be included to display a footer of my web pages
I want a php file to be included to display a footer of my web pages. I'm using godaddy shared hosting with php7.4.
I created a footer.php file like thus:
<?php
    echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
?>

A html file "test.html" to display the footer is like thus:
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
    <?php include 'footer.php';?>
</body>
</html>

The result displays the test.html file without the footer file display.
Thanks in advance for any positive solutions.
Cheers,
Dave
As stated above, it didn't display the footer file verbiage.

.html files typically do not run PHP code, unless the server is specifically configured to do so (which is very unlikely with shared hosting). Rename your file to test.php and it should work.

Renaming the test.html file to test.php is not an option. I have hundreds of html files that I want this to apply. What is another option? Thanks for you quick response.

@Ddaved, it's not possible to write PHP code in HTML files. You can write PHP file with router, include there all your HTML files, and add your code with footer

You could do a bulk rename with a script. And maybe even bulk insert of the footer with a clever regex

For your informaton, HTML file cannot render PHP commands under normal circumstances.
However, you may use a small trick to do the job
Assuming that your footer is a php (footer.php)
<?php
    echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " xxxx.com</p>";
?>

Then you may use

a DIV to display the footer
Use jquery load to put the footer contents there

So the code will be:

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="footerplace" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"></div>


<script>
$("#footerplace").load("footer.php");
</script>


So the following will be a sample:


Test <br>
Test2 <br>
Test3 <br>
Test4 <br>
Test5 <br>



<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="footerplace" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"></div>


<script>
$("#footerplace").load("footer.php");
</script>


The result will be like:


Modify you code as below in html files

  <html>
   <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 1999- <script>document.write(/\d{4}/.exec(Date())[0])</script>  W3Schools.com</p>
   </body>
 </html>


Make Bulk file replace in any notepad ++ like editor with
replace in file
Your php include file line

 <?php include 'footer.php';?>


with

  <p>Copyright &copy; 1999- <script>document.write(/\d{4}/.exec(Date())[0])</script>  W3Schools.com</p> 


Other method is to make apache interpret html files as php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs>
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
AddType text/html .php .html .htm
</Directory>
</IfModule>


refer to this link
https://www.plesk.com/kb/support/how-to-configure-apache-to-process-php-code-inside-an-html-file-on-a-plesk-server/
This is not just for plesk server but can be used for any apache based server if you have access to these files.
